# realloc(): invalid next size in strtok operation

Tags: c, realloc, calloc

in this part of my program, I am trying to mimic the CDUP operation in ftp servers. First I get the current directory the client is at (`ptr2` and `buf3`) and then I attempt to strip off the last string separated by `/` in order to determine what the path would be if we went up a directory. However I am getting a realloc error only when I go in another directory, come back out, and attempt to CDUP again (i.e go upwards from the root directory)

```
                char *ptr2;
                char buf3[255];
                // Get current directory of application, store in buf3
                if ((ptr2 = getcwd(buf3, sizeof(buf3))) != NULL) {
                    printf("Current working dir CDUP: %s\n", buf3);
                } else {
                    perror("getcwd() error");
                }

                // Strip current directory off buf3 
                char *cdupSplit = strtok(buf3, "/");
                char *cdupAccumulator = NULL;
                char *newStr = calloc(1, strlen(cdupSplit));
                while (cdupSplit != NULL) {
                    if (cdupAccumulator != NULL) {
                        newStr = realloc(newStr, strlen("/"));
                        newStr = realloc(newStr, strlen(cdupAccumulator));
                        strcat(newStr, "/");
                        strcat(newStr, cdupAccumulator);
                    }
                    cdupAccumulator = cdupSplit;
                    cdupSplit = strtok(NULL, "/");
                }
                ...
                free(newStr);
```

The error says `realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000001ac0a20 ***`

I'm not sure where I am going wrong, as I am freeing the `newStr` variable and it is not being passed into the next issue of the command.

Comment: You're reducing the size of `newStr` with your `realloc()`s. After `newStr = realloc(newStr, strlen("/"));` the object has space just for the `'\0'` string terminator

Comment: @pmg Would the correction be `realloc(newStr, strlen(newStr) + strlen("/"));`? Can't believe I missed that error. Thank you!

Comment: You're forgetting that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. You need to allocate space for the null-terminator as well.

Comment: Also `strlen("/")`, for me, is much more difficult to parse than `1` :)

Comment: @JCI no, that is not sufficient. See my answer

Comment: @pmg *Also `strlen("/")`, for me, is much more difficult to parse than `1`*  I'll grant that `strlen("/")` certainly indicates the intent of the code better than `1` does, however.

Comment: regarding: `char *newStr = calloc(1, strlen(cdupSplit));`  The function: `strlen()` returns the OFFSET to the trailing NUL byte (assuming there is such a byte)  So to allocated enough room for the string, must add 1 to the value returned from `strlen()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part does not make much sense:

```
             if (cdupAccumulator != NULL) {
                    newStr = realloc(newStr, strlen("/"));
                    newStr = realloc(newStr, strlen(cdupAccumulator));
                    strcat(newStr, "/");
                    strcat(newStr, cdupAccumulator);
                }
```

You keep adding new stuff to the string but resize it again and again to only hold the last part.

You seem to assume that `realloc` increases the size be the given parameter. This is not the case. (Even then there is no space for terminating \0)
You need to keep track of the current size and add to this size accordingly.

For example like this:

```
if (cdupAccumulator != NULL) {
                newStr = realloc(newStr, strlen(newStr) + strlen(cdupAccumulator) + 2);
                strcat(newStr, "/");
                strcat(newStr, cdupAccumulator);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, so the corrections would be to include the current size of the variable into realloc plus the new size and at also somewhere add 1 byte for the termination \0 ?

Comment: Correct. I added `2` to include the `'/'` character as well.